# Audio converter / transcoder

Tags: audio

I've been trying to search around for a audio transcoder for linux where i can set specific presets, maybe batch transcode say a wav file into diffrently converted mp3 files (using diffrent codecs,bitrate etc)

Does any of you know of sutch a software?

Comment: Have a look at ffmpeg or handbrake, if you prefer a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `sox` and/or `ffmpeg` for that purpose.

As I wouldn't do better than Stefaan Lippens, here is [his page about that topic](http://stefaanlippens.net/audio_conversion_cheat_sheet).

To install `sox` and enable MP3 reading and writing:

```
sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
```

If you are particularly looking for fine-tune MP3 encoding, you should consider using `lame` (discussed on [Stefaan Lippens' page](http://stefaanlippens.net/audio_conversion_cheat_sheet) too).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We like answers to be more comprehensive here. Please edit your answer and add installation and usage instructions so the OP can know how to apply the tools you suggest to solve their issue.